# Running coded test UI with jenkins as part of CI

Tags: jenkins, coded-ui-tests

We currently have coded UI regression test suite (UI function test) which runs perfectly using MTM on test anent/controller.

As part of CI our team is using Jenkins. Here we want to integrate coded UI test with Jenkins. Can you please tell me how can I configure this?

Is there a way Jenkins will access the TFS build of my coded UI test project which will have test run setting file (with info of test controller and agent to run test)?

I don't want to run coded UI tests on Jenkins server (but on test agent) as it will need to have a active desktop session.

Answer (score 1):

A great example of running UI with Jenkins is executing [selenium tests](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-jenkins/). This approach suggests you to run browser and simulate user actions. The same you can do with your UI and basically this does not require any additional configuration steps except slave configuration. You need to use [Slave Configuration via Java Web Start](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-LaunchslaveagentviaJavaWebStart) as only this gives you ability to interact with Desktop:

> If you need display interaction (e.g. for GUI tests) on Windows and you have a dedicated (virtual) test machine, this is a suitable option.

Other slave configuration ways may just not run your UI.